# Djaongo: ModelChoiceField and Widget - Could not display non-foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelchoicefield

I want to create a select field that displays a list of records from a column that is not a foreign key. I am able to do it using

```
widget=ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(rel=Slum._meta.get_field('electoral_ward').rel
```

where 'electoral_ward' is a foreign key in 'Slum' model.

But, I wish to have the same behavior for a field ('name') which is just a char field in 'Slum' model.

EDIT: 
I have a custom form (not a model form). In that form, I wish to have a selection field which will have slum names in the list. Instead of having a simple drop-down I need to have a raw field widget which will show a pop-up for selection. 
How do I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with models and with a example.